# Trustpilot: window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement is undefined (Safari)

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined, trustpilot

I want to put 3 trustPilots in my Angular app.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare global {
    interface Window { Trustpilot: any; }
}
 
window.Trustpilot = window.Trustpilot || {};

@Component({
    selector: 'app-trustbox-normal',
    templateUrl: './trustbox-normal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./trustbox-normal.component.scss']
})
export class TrustboxNormalComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void { }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        const trustboxRef = document.getElementById('trustbox');
        window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement(trustboxRef);
    }

}
```

On the Brave, and Firefox works fine, but in Safari i got an error:
window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement is not a function. (In 'window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement(trustboxRef)', 'window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement' is undefined)

Answer (score 1):

I removed `window.Trustpilot = window.Trustpilot || {};` from the code, and now it's working ok also on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this [Trustpilot TrustBoxes in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476769/trustpilot-trustboxes-in-next-js)

Have you tried adding a delay to the call of the loadFromElement to give enough time to the Truspilot js script to load?

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.